# How do I disable a prettier plugin?

Tags: plugins, prettier

We are working on a Salsforce project that includes flows. Because of this, we get permission set files that include the `<flow>` tag. `prettier` [apparently has a plugin](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-xml/issues/751#issuecomment-1900850165) for (I think) the [Flow](https://flow.org) static type checker, which we don't use. But because of this plugin, `prettier` interprets the `<flow>` tag as containing an embedded language. So this:

```xml
<flow>Mock_Case_Screen_Flow</flow>
```

turns into this:

```xml
<flow>
Mock_Case_Screen_Flow;
</flow>
```

The comment in the above linked GitHub issue did fix the problem (adding `"embeddedLanguageFormatting": "off"` to our `.prettierrc`), but then another problem surfaced because of it. We're working with Lightning Web Components, which access JavaScript properties from HTML like this:

```html
<lightning-card
    hide-header={hideHeader}
    title={titleText}
    icon-name={cardIcon}
>
```

Apparently `prettier` interprets this as embedded, and properly ignores it without the above addition to `.prettierrc`, but when we add that line to the config file, `prettier` now mangles this to:

```html
<lightning-card
    hide-header="{hideHeader}"
    title="{titleText}"
    icon-name="{cardIcon}"
>
```

Since we don't use the Flow language and will never need to have `prettier` format Flow code, how can we just disable this one plugin for the entire project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'd like to just disable the flow plugin, a solution that worked was to have an XML-specific override in `.prettierrc`:

```
{
    "files": "*.xml",
    "options": { "embeddedLanguageFormatting": "off" }
}
```

This prevents the mangling of the XML files while retaining the format of the HTML files.